# Push on Heroku for Symfony project is failing

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm trying to push my Symfony project on Heroku but it fails.
I encounter this error :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
remote:         [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
remote:        !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle" not found in /tmp/build_d6c3170f/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php:94
```

I don't understand the reason.
APP_ENV in the ENV file is set on PROD, same for the Heroku env.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.6",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.9",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^3",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "symfony/asset": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/google-mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/validator": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.3.*",
        "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.33",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.2",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.12"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the file bundle.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\SymfonyCastsVerifyEmailBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\EasyAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\ApiPlatformBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

I have searched on the web but I don't find any solution.
Do you have any idea where it could come from ?

Comment: I have added the config/bundles.php file in the question, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your composer.json, you install webpack-encore as a dev dependency, which means that you can use it only when you are in dev mode (APP_ENV = dev)

If you app is a symfony application, you can install it as a mandatory dependency by doing :

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

and :

```
npm install
```

Comment: Indeed, but should I really put it in prod also? I use this bundle to compile my source files to generate the css and js files. Those are already in the public folder

Comment: You'll need webpack-encore-bundle support for the twig methods `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('entry') }}` to load in your templates. So it should not be in `require-dev`. However `npm install` should NOT be used in `prod` since you should run `yarn encore production` BEFORE deploying to production.

Comment: There are two components involving the npm/yarn usage in dev and the Symfony bundle usage in dev and prod. The idea is that npm modules are not needed in prod since they are pre-compiled before being deployed to prod. As such nodejs/npm/yarn does not need to be installed in the prod environment.